# Chain rule for $f(t,\Phi(t,x))$ in the context of smooth manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-derivative, smooth-manifolds, chain-rule

Let $M$ be a smooth $n$-manifold, let $f(t,y):(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\times M\to\mathbb R$, and let $\Phi(t,x):(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\times M\to M$ be defined so that given each $t$, $\Phi(t,x)$ is a diffeomorphism. Then we define a vector field $X_t$ so that $X_t(\Phi(t,x))=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Phi(t,x)$. I was wondering if we have a chain rule for $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(t,\Phi(t,x))$ using the information above. Thank you.

This question is easy to tackle in the setting of Euclidean spaces, but, with $x$ and $y$ both ranging over an abstract manifold, I'm stuck:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(t,\Phi(t,x))&=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}\\
&=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(t,\Phi(t,x))+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(t,\Phi(t,x))\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial t}(t,x)
\end{align}$$
How do we interpret $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$?
I looked through my DG books but didn't find anything. Do we have to impose a Riemannian metric on $M$ to discuss this question? Could someone please shed light on this topic? Thank you.

Comment: Do the calculation in coordinates and then realize it has an invariant expression. Note that $\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial t}(t,x)$ is a (time-dependent) vector field on $M$.

Comment: P.S. Riemannian metrics are not relevant.

Comment: If you have $g\colon M\to\Bbb R$ and you write this as $g(x)$, what is the meaning of $g'(p) = dg/dx\big|_{x=p}$? It's the derivative $Dg(p)\colon T_pM\to T_{f(p)}\Bbb R \cong \Bbb R$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Are you suggesting that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is a covector field (differential $1$-form) with $f$ being your $g$ because of fixed $t$? Thank you.

Comment: Sure, you can certainly think of $df$ as a $1$-form. Locally you can express it as a linear combination of $dt$ and $dx^1,\dots, dx^n$, where $(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ is a coordinate chart on $M$.